# Storing optional attributes in DynamoDB's putItem via step functions

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

I have defined a state machine in AWS step functions and one of my states is storing an item to DynamoDB

```json
...
"Store item": {
  "End": true,
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:putItem",
  "Parameters": {
    "Item": {
      "foo": {
        "S.$": "$.data.foo"
      },
      "bar": {
        "S.$": "$.data.bar"
      },
      "baz": {
        "S.$": "$.data.baz"
      },
    },
    "TableName": "nrp_items"
  }
},
...
```

The problem starts from the fact that `baz` property is optional, ie not exist in some cases.
On those cases, the `putItem` task fails:

> An error occurred while executing the state 'Store item' (entered at the event id #71). > The JSONPath '$.data.baz' specified for the field 'S.$' could not be found in the input

My backup plan is to use a lambda to perform that type of operation, but can I do it directly using the `putItem` task in steps function?

I was wondering if:

1. Is possible to somehow inject via JSONPath my whole `$.data` item to the "Item" property, something like:

```json
...
"Store item": {
  "End": true,
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:putItem",
  "Parameters": {
    "Item": "$.data",
    "TableName": "nrp_items"
  }
},
...
```

OR
2) Define that the baz property is optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** We can deal with optional variables with a `"Variable": "$.baz", "IsPresent": true` Choice condition to handle no-baz cases.

The [Amazon States Language spec](https://states-language.net/spec.html) does not have optional properties: Step Functions will throw an error if `$.baz` does not exist in the input.  We can avoid undefined paths by inserting a two-branch [Choice State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html), one branch of which handles baz-exists cases, the other no-baz cases.  Each branch continues with a [Pass State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html) that reworks the `data` input into dynamo-format `Item` syntax, using [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters).  The put-item task's `"Item.$": "$.data"` (as in your #1) contains only foo-bar when baz is not defined, but all three otherwise.

```json
{
  "StartAt": "HasBazChoice",
  "States": {
    "HasBazChoice": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.baz",
          "IsPresent": true,
          "Next": "MakeHasBazItem"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "MakeNoBazItem"
    },
    "MakeHasBazItem": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "data": {
          "foo": { "S.$": "$.foo"},
          "bar": { "S.$": "$.bar"},
          "baz": { "S.$": "$.baz"}
        }
      },
      "Next": "PutItemTask"
    },
    "MakeNoBazItem": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "data": {
          "foo": {"S.$": "$.foo"},
          "bar": {"S.$": "$.bar"}
        }
      },
      "Next": "PutItemTask"
    },
    "PutItemTask": {
      ...
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "my-table",
        "Item.$": "$.data"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

If you have more than one optional field, your lambda backup plan is the better option - the above workaround would become unwieldy.

Comment: Thanks for the info provided! I suppose that I could use the lambda scenario since it looks cleaner solution to me. There could be more optional parameters.
However, you also demonstrated another piece of syntax: ```"Item.$": "$.data"```. Perhaps an alternative scenario could be to prepare my data with the appropriate dynamodb syntax beforehand (i.e. from the previous execution state)